# match a range on query function in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, index-match

I am trying to create an arrayformula that matches the column from a certain sheet to the current sheet.
I have a list of names (Column B) in sheet1 with its value (Column C), and in sheet2 i have all the names in a different order, and i want to bring their respective values to the current sheet, i have tried the following formula but it only matches the first value which is A2 and not the rest to the A14

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Match";IF(ISBLANK(A2:A14),"",IFERROR(QUERY(Sheet1!$B$2:$C$14, "select C where B matches '"&A2:A&"' "),0))})
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

[Link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit#gid=1682305544)

Comment: I would recommend **VLOOKUP:** `=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A1:A,Sheet7!$B:$C,2,0)),"")` Or drag down: `=QUERY({Sheet7!$B1:$C},"Select Col2 where Col1 = '"&$A1:$A&"'")`

Comment: @KevinP. - I believe your `VLOOKUP` answer is the right answer for OP's issue. Could you please post it as answer? Also kindly change the sheet name to Sheet1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet1!B:C, 2, )))
```

[image]

Comment: this did trick! thnx